# Radio Button Not Working on Click

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

This is my first question so please forgive me if I am unclear, ask an ignorant question or break any written unwritten programming rules. I am a very beginner coder and promise that is not my intention!

I am working on a simple donation form for my company. There will be a set of buttons where a donor can choose from designated predetermined amounts or manually enter their own amount. I am using radio buttons that I have designed to look like block buttons. I am having trouble getting the button to stay checked (the selected button should stay red). I have tried everything I can think for troubleshooting and feel like I'm right back where I started. Any help is so greatly appreciated!

```css
.amount_list input {
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d50032;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d50032;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
.amount_list {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}
.gift_amount:hover {
  background: #d50032;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.gift_amount + input:checked {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  background: #d50032;
  border: 1px solid #d50032;
  opacity: ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
#inputother {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount_list">
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="1000" name="amount" />$1,000</label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="500" name="amount" />$500</label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="250" name="amount" />$250</label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="100" name="amount" />$100</label>
  <label class="gift_amount" for="other">
    <input type="radio" value="other" name="amount" id="other">Other</label>
  <input id="inputother" type="text" onchange="changeradioother()" />
</div>
```

As I mentioned, I am a novice when it comes to coding so any mistakes, sloppy code or bad habits it looks I can learn from, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Comment: @Dekel It isn't needed for this question

Comment: @JacobGray, he said he has a problem with "on click" on a button... I assumed the problem was with the javascript (that is missing here)

Comment: @Dekel Yes, a _radio_ button (which the title says very clearly), which does not need script to respond to a click

Comment: @Dekel fair enough

Comment: And I believe _he_ is a _she_ ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to style an elements parent, which can't be done with CSS.

Wrap the price in a `<span>`, and style that instead:

```css
.amount_list input {
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label span {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d50032;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d50032;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
.amount_list {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}
.gift_amount:hover span {
  background: #d50032;
  color: #fff;
}
.gift_amount input:checked + span {
  background: #d50032;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount_list">
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="1000" name="amount" />
    <span>$1,000</span>
  </label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="500" name="amount" />
    <span>$500</span>
  </label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="250" name="amount" />
    <span>$250</span>
  </label>
  <label class="gift_amount">
    <input type="radio" value="100" name="amount" />
    <span>$100</span>
  </label>
  <label class="gift_amount" for="other">
    <input type="radio" value="other" name="amount" id="other">
    <span>Other</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a wizard! This worked perfectly! I don't know if I want to cry, scream or jump for joy...or all three. I thought I was going to lose my mind before I got it to work. Thank you so much! I appreciate it so much!

Comment: @CarolineK np, glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you have to make a markup change + correction of the CSS rule, where you put the `input` before the `label` and swap the CSS to

```
input:checked + .gift_amount {...}
```

An `id` is also needed along with the `for` attribute, to pair the `label` with its `input`

Sample

```css
.amount_list input {
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d50032;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d50032;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
.amount_list {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}
.gift_amount:hover {
  background: #d50032;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
input:checked + .gift_amount {
  background: #d50032;
  border: 1px solid #d50032;
  opacity: ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
#inputother {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount_list">
  
  <input id="a1000" type="radio" value="1000" name="amount" />
  <label for="a1000" class="gift_amount">$1,000</label>

  <input id="a500" type="radio" value="500" name="amount" />
  <label for="a500" class="gift_amount">$500</label>

</div>
```